# Mask Keyframes not showing in graph editor

Tags: compositing-nodes, keyframes, masking, graph-editor, dopesheet

Blender has a masking system which is available in both the Image Editor and the Movie clip editor. The issue however is that when you add key frames to the mask, it shows up on the dopesheet but not in the graph editor. Is there a fix for this or we’d have to frame by frame the masks to get what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is very pour support for mask's control points  animation.
The only one place to access mask's keyframes is in the **Dope Sheet** in the **Mask** category.

[image]

Comment: Could you show where? Perhaps post a few screenshots illustrating it